# Pandas - Number of Months Between Two Dates in Month year format

Tags: python

I have dates in format of Jan-09, Jan-18 where 09 and 18 are years. How do I code to find the number of months between these two days. I tried using this code:

```
ata4['mob_try'] = ((data4.last_pymnt_date - data4.issue_date)/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')).

data4['mob'] = data4['mob_try'].astype(int)
```

but there is an error "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'"
how do I resolve this??

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetime` and [`relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) to achieve this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta
date1 = datetime.strptime(str('Jan-09'), '%b-%y')
date2 = datetime.strptime(str('Jan-18'), '%b-%y')
r = relativedelta.relativedelta(date2, date1)

total_months = r.years*12 + r.months

print("Total months: {0}".format(total_months))
```

Answer (score 0):

On which line this error occurs? If it's on the 1st line, maybe **last_pymnt_date** or **issue_date** columns are still stored as `int`. In this case, you must use `pd.to_datetime()` on each one first.

This example should work:

> d1 = pd.to_datetime(data4.last_pymnt_date)
>
> d2 = pd.to_datetime(data4.issue_date)
>
> data4['mob'] = (d1 - d2) // np.timedelta64(1, 'M'))

Comment: error here. while running the first line of code itself. 

"Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-10-11 00:00:00"


i further check the data type. it is saved as a string. when i try to change it into int it again shows an error